# where clause and aggregate function

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like below. I need to find fourth column for previous financial year only. I cannot use aggregate function after where clause.My input table is first 3 columns and expected result is column 4. FY20 means Jan1 to Dec31. Any help appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSXse.png)

Comment: Could you share the code you've attempted but failed?

Comment: @  tidakdiinginkan, I was thinking something like it but i know i cannot use aggregate function after where clause. ,select value where ReportFY=max(ReportFY
)-1 as PreviousReportFY

Comment: I didn't understand the sample table. Can you explain it better?

Comment: Hi. 
It is really important that you share the query you tried to use, the code. Please try